# Proving Riemann integrability of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Define a function $f$ by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}42 & \text{if }x =1,2,3,4;  
\\0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0,5]$ by using the box-sum criterion.

---

My work:

$$BS(f,P) = (M_1-m_1)\Delta x_1 + (M_2-m_2)\Delta x_2 + \dots + (M_9-m_9)\Delta x_9 = 0 + 42\Delta x_2 + 0 + 42\Delta x_4 + \dots + 42\Delta x_8 + 0 = 42(\Delta x_2+\Delta x_4+\Delta x_6+\Delta x_8).$$

We choose $\Delta x_2$,$\Delta x_4$, $\Delta x_6$, and $\Delta x_8$ so that $\Delta x_2+\Delta x_4+\Delta x_6+\Delta x_8<\frac{\epsilon}{42}$.

This satisfies the box-sum criterion and therefore $f:[0,5]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

How does everything look?

Comment: What is the "box-sum criterion"? According to Google, you may be the only person who knows what it is. https://www.google.com/search?q="box-sum+criterion"

Comment: Haha not really. Here is the theorem: Let $f:\left [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. So f is integrable on $\left [ a,b \right ]$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exits a partition $P$ with $BS(f,P) = US(f,P) - LS(f,P)<\epsilon$, then f is integrable on $[a,b]$. For reference look at Paul Zorn's Understanding Real Analysis textbook.

Comment: Looks good. My only suggestion is that you describe a specific partition. For example: Let $x_1=1-\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_2=1+\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_3=2-\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_4=2+\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, etc. Then you can give the sums explicitly: the lower sum is zero, and the upper sum is $4\cdot\left(42\cdot\displaystyle\frac{2\epsilon}{42\cdot9}\right)< \epsilon$.

Comment: @SteveKass Please consider undeleting your answer; it's one as good as this question will ever get, and it doesn't deserve its current "unanswered" status.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for the suggestion, and done.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. My only suggestion is that you describe a specific partition. For example: Let $x_1=1-\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_2=1+\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_3=2-\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, $x_4=2+\epsilon/(42\cdot9)$, etc. Then you can give the sums explicitly: the lower sum is zero, and the upper sum is $4\cdot\left(42\cdot\displaystyle\frac{2\epsilon}{42\cdot9}\right)< \epsilon$.